# How to make the below function work by changing only last line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### Problem Statement

Goal: The function `closest_higher_mod_5` takes exactly one integer argument `x` and returns the smallest integer `y` such that:

1. `y` is greater than or equal to `x`,
2. `y` is divisible by 5.

Correct the last line of the code below to make the function work.

#### Expected Result

Sample Input 1:
43

Sample Output 1:
45

Actual Result:
My answer is coming as 44 instead of 45

#### my code:

```
def closest_higher_mod_5(x):
    remainder = x % 5
    if remainder == 0:
        return x
    y = x + 1
    return  y
```

Comment: This seems like homework. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) I'm glad you got some good answers, but in the future, we'll want to know what you've already tried, and what the outcome was. As well, it's helpful to mention why you think your current solution doesn't work. See [ask] if you want more advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good. You just need to change one line:

```py
y = x + (5 - remainder)
```

That's it. What you do is add how much in needed to get from x to 5.

Answer (score -3):

This would be much easier...

```
def func(x):
    while True:
        if x % 5 == 0:
            return x
        x += 1


print(func(42))
```

You just keep increasing x until it is divisible by 5. If so, we return that value.

Comment: I agree. This is much easier, but the question is asking how to make the **user's** function work, not make your own. Please change your answer to answer the actual question. Thanks.